# JavaCV: How to Find Significant points in a binary image

Tags: opencv, expression, binary-data, javacv

I am having a problem with this project of mine implemented using JavaCV. I want to find at least, the top-most, bottom-most, left-most and right-most points in a binary image:

[image: Happy Mouth Binary image]

Points I mean here are (x,y) coordinates. I have tried implementing HoughLines (it only detects lines but not the curves) and cvFindContours but I just can't extract the coordinates properly.  I'm still a novice, if only I know what is the value of the white lines as well as the background, then maybe I could just loop around the image.

Is there an easier way out? Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Hay have you found any solution for this ? If so please share you answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop here to find the most left, right, top and bottom points. However, you need to think on how to make a smart loop. You could just loop through all pixels, but you could also use a smarter approach. For instance, the left most point is probably somewhere on the left. So if you use a scanline which goes from left to right you might be more likely to find this pixel than if you would just scan top->bottom. This being said, it is quite easy to get the values from an image.

Let's say we have an image `binaryImg` with *n* channels. In case of a gray scale image *n* should be 1, but in case of a color image *n* should be 3. Let's say we have the indices `0 <= y < height`, `0 <= x < width` and `0 <= k < n`. We can the value of a pixel(x, y) as follows:

```
((uchar *)(binaryImg->imageData + y*binaryImg->widthStep))[x*binaryImg->nChannels + k]
```

Since a gray image has only a single channel, we can check if a pixel is white using:

```
((uchar *)(binaryImg->imageData + y*binaryImg->widthStep))[x] == 255
```

In terms of speed, this solution will give a worst case time of O(n), but in practice you will not have to look through all pixels.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vector of points like `std::vector<cv::Point2f> pts` then you can use opencv `cv::boundingRect` method which computes the up-right bounding rectangle of your point set.
Use it like this:

```
// this is your set of floating point (filled vector)
std::vector<cv::Point2f> pts;
// convert to matrix
cv::Mat ptsmat(pts);
// compute the bounding rectangle 
cv::Rect bbox = cv::boundingRect(ptsmat);
```

I used c++ opencv api but you could use corresponding function in javacv

Comment: You are assuming here that KnighK has already found his set of white points and that's one of the questions he's asking. Also, it is not most efficient since you're saying he should find all white points, while he's merely interested in the most left, right, top and bottom points.

Comment: Right, I went to fast on his question. I would add a suggestion: he should use opencv c++ api with cv::Mat object representing an image and accessing (more easily) to pixel value (mat.at(x,y))